# Does using Bootstrap mean mixing content and layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My understanding of CSS is that the point of its existence is to allow the developer to separate the content from the layout.

Thus for example, the html `<center>` tag was deprecated in favour of using an html element like `<div>`, giving it a class, and then using CSS to define that class as being centred. This means that you can change the layout of the page without having to make any changes to your HTML.

So far so good. I understand that.

However, Bootstrap seems to go against that.

Writing code for Bootstrap involves adding lots of classes to your code with names like `col-12` or `text-center`.

Yes, these are class names, but they are very much defining the layout; if you use these classes, then as far as I can see, you're defining your layout in the HTML.

Given that, I am struggling to understand what the advantage is of using Bootstrap? It seems to be a step backward. Can anyone explain why Bootstrap does things this way? What is the advantage of `<div class='text-center'>` compared with an old-style `<center>` tag?

[edit]
Let's say I have an error message and I want to to be shown in red. That doesn't mean I should give it a class name `bold-red-text`. I give it a class name like `error-message`, and then write CSS for `.error-message` to style it as bold and red. Then when I change my site design and decide to make the errors show up in a different font or something, I can just change the CSS, not the HTML.

And that's my problem with most of what Bootstrap does; if I change my mind about an element being centred or six columns wide, or whatever, I have to make that change in the HTML, which as far as I can see defeats the point of having separate CSS in the first place.

But Bootstrap seems to be massively popular and well respected, so I'm looking for someone to come out and show me how I'm completely missing the point and how actually it is good practice to use it.

Comment: Yes. Your concerns are spot on. The advantages of Bootstrap are very much similar to the advantages of `<center>`. It's easy for beginners who struggle with the CSS abstraction.

Comment: Not quote `text-center` doesn't actually define layout. It defines what happens to the content inside the element. For that matter `center` didn't define layout either...it just wasn't *semantic*

Comment: @Paulie_D - the point is not what it defines, but the fact that it defines anything at all.

Comment: Most people use it just because of the ease of use it provides. It is ultimately a library that aims to tackle common day to day issues a developer may face, eliminating the need for boilerplate code, amongst many other things. Helpful link: https://www.devsaran.com/blog/10-best-reasons-use-bootstrap-amazing-web-designs

Comment: But that's not what you asked. ***This has nothing to do with layout***. **Why shouldn't a helper class be descriptive of what it does** ...that's the point.

Comment: I used the 'center' example because it was less wordy to explain than talking about cols and tables, but I'd make the same point for them, and other things in Bootstrap too.

Comment: At the end of the day *all* CSS must be declared in HTML.  A framework might choose descriptive classes (like `text-center`) but it could just as easily just be `bs-class-14293b`.  The advantage to the former is that as a developer you have a pretty good idea of what the class does.

Comment: @RobertC - Nope. *HTML classes* - note, not "CSS classes" - should describe the content of the elements, not their styling. The styling is bound to the HTML - types, ids, classes, and other attributes - via *selectors*.

Comment: @RobertC: well no. Let's say I have an error message. I don't give it a class name `bold-red-text`, I give it a class name `error-message`, and then write CSS for `.error-message` to make it bold and red. Then when I change my site design and make the errors show up in a different font or something, I just change the CSS, not the HTML. And that's my problem with most of what Bootstrap does; if I change my mind about an element being centred or six columns wide, or whatever, I have to make that change in the HTML, which defeats the point of having separate CSS in the first place.

Comment: But Bootstrap seems to be massively popular and well respected, so I'm looking for someone to come out and show me how I'm completely missing the point and how it really is good practice to use it.

Answer (score -1):

In the `<center>` tag you cant add any other css. For adding CSS you have to make another class. 
But Using `<div class='text-center'>`, you can still add css in class `text-center`, if you want. This gives extra control. As `text-align:center` is present by default so u have to only put rest necessary CSS in that class. Thus, this reduce the CSS code.

Comment: What you're describing (directly modifying a frameworks CSS) is considered bad practice.  Good practice is to add a custom class name with your UI-specific alterations, which runs contrary to your argument here.

Comment: Thank you. I just realize i was following bad trend.